# Why do I still get my association bonus?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

After I deleted my Code Golf.SE account, (my only account eligible for the association bonus), I still get the association bonus (see my rep). Is there a reason why this happens (or, if this is erroneous, can it be fixed)?

Comment: Can I ask you why you deleted your account in the first place?

Comment: I've VTCed this as off-topic as it's not directly related to PPCG and belongs on Mother Meta.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164224/566903), the association bonus can never be revoked from an account once it has been earned.